# Получение названия страны на английском

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Всем добрый день.

Обнаружил интересное свойства метода `getCountries` апи контакта: метод может возвращать данные на различных языках (в зависимости от языка владельца аккаунта, для которого `getCountries` вызывается). В то же время хочется получать название страны исключительно на английском. Делаю запрос с помощью `file_get_contents`:

```
    $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
        )
    );

    $c = stream_context_create($opts);
    $r = json_decode(@file_get_contents("https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/getCountries?$params" .
    "&sig=....", false, $this->getRequestContext()))->response;

    $name = $r[0]->name; //name на русском :-(
```

Есть ли возможность получить название страны на английском?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Может, вы не до конца упростили код для примера, но именно в примере у вас не передаётся контекст в `file_get_contents()`. Надо бы так:

    $r = json_decode(
        @file_get_contents(
            "https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/getCountries?$params" .
    "&sig=....", 
            false,
            $c
        )
    )->response;

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с похожей темой в контексте языка имён: VK упорно отдавал их латиницей, "Vasya Pupkin". Как оказалось, на это влияла комбинация страны сервера (Amazon EC2 в штатах) и предпочтительный язык "браузера", которым в данном случае был php cURL. Когда сделал русский — жизнь наладилась.

Добавьте заголовок предпочитаемого языка, что-то вроде:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5'));
```

Comment: я подозреваю мне тоже надо через curl работать.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от того какой язык в настройках твоего профиля, если там русский, тогда названия будут на русском, если инглиш, то на инглише будут страны и города.

Иначе вроде никак.